# PIP version VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip

I am having troubles trying to understand why VSCode uses a different `pip` version.

I have two python versions installed in Windows, `python38` and `python39`, if I open the win 10 terminal I got pip version `20.2.4` when running `pip3 --version`, but if i run the same command inside the VSCode terminal i got `pip 20.2.2` from `c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)`.

Both terminals are running `PowerShell 7.0.3` on the same profile.

Also removing python38 from the global PATH variable gives command not found error only in vscode, in windows terminal keeps working as i described before.

Could not fix this so I deleted all temporary and profile data of vscode and can now run pip from within its terminal.

Comment: Do you have a virtual environment activated in the VSCode terminal?

Comment: no virtual environment, I am just running pip --verion from the shell

Comment: `pip3 --version` or `pip --version`? (although, there probably give always same version, unless also python 2 is installed on the system and PATH has a certain order)

Comment: both commands give the same version, which is 20.2.2 in vscode and 20.2.4 in windows terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears something got fixed after deleting all profile and settings data from visual studio code, it runs pip now form the terminal inside vscode.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your interpreter: `ctrl+shift+p`->`select python interpreter` and choose the one you want because  pip is part of the python environment, and therefore the version of pip you are using is tied to the active python interpreter (cc @DragonBobZ)

Comment: Adding to this, pip is part of the python environment, and therefore the version of pip you are using is tied to the active python interpreter

Comment: Already did this with python39 as my interpreter but it keeps using pip from python38 when running the command.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about the Process `PATH`. Check `$Env:PATH` in both. Starting from the left, the first folder with `pip3.exe` is used. You have probably selected a python interpreter for VS Code, which then adds it in the `PATH`.

You can also check the location of the used `pip3.exe` with `Get-Command pip3`. (might be helpful in debugging)

Comment: this is part of my path variable in both terminals C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7;C:\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Python39\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Python38\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;

Comment: what is the output of `Get-Command pip3` in VS Code Terminal?

Comment: Application     pip3.exe                                           0.0.0.0    C:\Python38\Scripts\pip3.exe

Comment: for some reason vscode terminal skips the python39 path for the pip command, or gives preference to pip command which appears more at the end

Comment: Are you sure of the output of `$Env:PATH`? (especially, the output in VSCode Terminal) Since there is `C:\Python39\Scripts` *before* `C:\Python38\Scripts`, the output of `Get-Command pip3` should be `C:\Python39\Scripts\pip3.exe` (and not the Python38).

Comment: Thats correct C:\Python39\Scripts appears first from the vscode terminal output

Comment: So for some reason the VSCode Terminal does not respect the Process PATH. That's very interesting. I'm considering deleting my answer if it really does not help at all.

Comment: One other thing that comes to my mind is the `python.pythonPath` settings. Try removing any `C:\Python38\Scripts` paths from `python.pythonPath` all of the settings (`Ctrl+Shift+P` -> Settings, User Settings, Workspace Settings, Default Settings..). See [Using Python environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)